# Visual Studio community edition windows phone app missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

My visual studio community edition doesn't have windows phone template. I am almost sure I had it when I installed Visual Studio when installed it freshly. Now i need open one of my project for windows phone 8.1 and solution can't be loaded.

[image]

I would like to restore windows phone app. How to do that?

My version of VS 2013 with Update 4

Answer (score 1):

If there is no Windows Phone template under *New Project* chances are that there is something wrong with the SDK (however I don't really see the problem since your screenshot shows the templates). Maybe a file or parts of the configuration went missing. That's no problem.

Just head over to the Windows dev center and reinstall the SDK: http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/downloads

Make sure that you grab the latest versions and updates as well. I also had that problem once and reinstalling did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have be using windows 8 to make windows phone apps